# C# panel drawing on button press

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

My apologies if I'm missing something simple here, but I've running in circles for some time now. In short, I'd like to update the panel graphics (panel will contain simple shapes like circles and rectangles) every time a button is pressed. The code would look something like this:

```
private void PanelGraphics()
{
    ClearThePanel();  //empties the panel
    FillThePanel();   //draws new shapes in the panel
}
```

The function would be then called every time a button is pressed, and I understand button_events well enough so that's not a problem. However, I have no idea how to pull off the PanelGraphics() function, and a few links about panel_paint events didn't help me much.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear... what do you mean by 'pulling off' the `PanelGraphics()` function?  Do you mean drawing things or using it?

Comment: Well... using the function in order to draw things, I presume. In any case, Itzalive provided a good solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw to the panel by creating a graphics controller to it.

```
Graphics g = panel.CreateGraphics();
```

You can then use the Graphic class's plethora of methods to draw whatever you want to the panel

```
g.DrawCurve(parameters);
g.DrawEllipse(parameters);
g.DrawLine(parameters);
g.DrawRectangle(parameters);
```

To clear the panel the easiest way is to draw a box the colour of the background to the panel

```
g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(panel.BackColor), new Rectangle(new Point(), panel.Size));
```

Comment: @MrLinjak Be careful with that CreateGraphics.  If you minimize your window and restore it, the drawing won't be there anymore.  You should be drawing in the Paint event of the panel or in a bitmap.

Comment: @LarsTech Ok, I'll keep it in mind.